# How to get back to app from browser in my phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a news listing app, and this app lists the title and content over internet to my app list view.

When we select list items it will redirect to browser. I am using CNN news feeds links. The problem is how to get back from browser to my app in devices (Android or iPhone)?

Comment: Try to use InAppBrowser or childbrowser to open the links with in the app.

Comment: @kalyanipuvvada is it solved?

Answer (score 0):

`InAppBrowser` is you solution; InAppBrowser is a web-browser that is shown in your app when you use the window.open call:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

for more clarification check [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html).